# Use jenkins to see if Jira is running

Tags: jenkins, jira, ping

I have a Jira installation on a Linux VM that crashes ever so often, I am the only user that has admin rights on the vm and I need a solution to autorestart Jira if I am not available. Due to budget constraints there is no option to update Jira at the moment.

I managed to create a jenkins job that can be manually triggered to restart Jira but I need something that triggers this when the Jira website is not available/ or if the service is not running.

I tried SiteMonitor but it always returns "503" even if the webiste is available.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: I would suggest to take the harder way and try to solve the problem why Jira always crashes. Have you had a look at the RAM or CPU consumption?... By the way, I just guessing, that Jira crashes and not the whole VM.

Comment: How about curl a specific page of your Jira and see if it's a success (with certain words in the result) or not?

Comment: I found out that the jenkins server was not connected to the DNS and needed the IP of the JIRA server instad of the hostname. It now works.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your version of Jira, you could use health check service to know if your Jira is running and is healthy. The details of this can be found out [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/how-to-retrieve-health-check-results-using-rest-api-867195158.html).

In short, `http://<jira-baseurl>/rest/troubleshooting/1.0/check/` should be able to tell about Jira health.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the jenkins server was not connected to the DNS and needed the IP of the JIRA server instad of the hostname. It now works by using Sitemonitor. 
Alternatively I could use  /rest/troubleshooting/1.0/check/

Thanks for your answers guys!